# How to Upload images into project folder using jquery with out server side code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using jquery ajax to save the data into server side webmethod, but right now i want to save image. here's the problem how can i save or send the image path to the server
 when i tried to get the val from filupload control it is throwing error in ajax call like

```
var img = $("input[id*=editfileuploadimage]").val();
```

the path came as :

> C:/fakepath/imagename.jpg

and when passing this through ajax it came as Internal server error. and it is not accepting,

how can i save the image along with data.

Comment: Are you saving your image in a database like SQL or you are just copying the physical file?

Comment: No i want to save the image in a project folder, so i want to take the path and send to webmethod in that method i want to save it in a specific folder

Answer (score 0):

you should include [ajaxupload](http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/235/ajaxupload.js) plugin.

Here is the JavaScript we're going to add in its entirety. You can also see it if you view the source of this page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var thumb = $('img#thumb');        

  new AjaxUpload('imageUpload', {
    action: $('form#newHotnessForm').attr('action'),
    name: 'image',
    onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
      $('div.preview').addClass('loading');
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response) {
      thumb.load(function(){
        $('div.preview').removeClass('loading');
        thumb.unbind();
      });
      thumb.attr('src', response);
    }
  });

});
```

see documentation at http://zurb.com/playground/ajax-upload